# WPF Key is digit or number

Tags: c#, wpf, key, keydown

I have `previewKeyDown` method in my window, and I'd like to know that pressed key is only `A-Z` letter or `1-0` number (without anyF1..12, enter, ctrl, alt etc - just letter or number).

I've tried `Char.IsLetter`, but i need to give the char, so `e.key.ToString()[0]` doesn't work, because it is almost everytime a letter.

Comment: Can you put some code to show what you intend?

Comment: A key is a key and not a character.

Answer (score 34):

Something like this will do:

```
if ((e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z) || (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9))
```

Of course you will also have to check that no modifier keys like CTRL are pressed according to your requirements.

Comment: That works fine, thank You.
Now another problem - focus on datagrid - in code i used something like: if (e.key == Key.Down || Key.Up) dataGrid.selectedIndex = 0; DataGrid.Focus(), but now pushing up/down key didnt change index in datagrid..

Comment: @AdamTruszkowski: Perhaps that's meant to be `e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up`? In any case, please ask separate questions instead of putting them in comments.

Comment: Yes, it is e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Down, but now i want to move up/down in datagrid when up/down is pressed

Comment: Ok, i got it - just changing index in datagrid +1/-1 after keydown/up pressed && when selecteditems.count = 1

Comment: KeyDown event does not capture arrow keys, try PreviewKeyDown instead.

Answer (score 11):

`e.Key` is giving you a member of the `enum` `System.Windows.Input.Key`

You should be able to do the following to determine whether it is a letter or a number:

```
var isNumber = e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9;
var isLetter = e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z;
```

Comment: This doesn't identify numbers coming from the numpad. isNumber should be (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) as used in Jon's answer.

Answer (score 6):

In your specific case the answer provided by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834382/302677) and [Jeffery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14834418/302677) is probably best, however if you need to test your string for some other letter/number logic then you can use the [KeyConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyconverter.aspx) class to convert a `System.Windows.Input.Key` to a string

```
var strKey = new KeyConverter().ConvertToString(e.Key);
```

You'll still need to check to see if any modifier keys are being held down (Shift, Ctrl, and Alt), and it should also be noted that this only works for Letters and Numbers. Special characters (such as commas, quotes, etc) will get displayed the same as `e.Key.ToString()`

Answer (score 5):

try this, it works.

```
    private void txbNumber_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) ; // it`s number
        else if (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9) ; // it`s number
        else if (e.Key == Key.Escape || e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.CapsLock || e.Key == Key.LeftShift || e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl ||
            e.Key == Key.LWin || e.Key == Key.LeftAlt || e.Key == Key.RightAlt || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightShift ||
            e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Right || e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Delete ||
            e.Key == Key.System) ; // it`s a system key (add other key here if you want to allow)
        else
            e.Handled = true; // the key will sappressed
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic and use the VB IsNumeric function, combined with char.IsLetter().

Answer (score 0):

bit of a cludge but it works :)

```
 private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex R = new Regex("^([A-Z]|[0-9]){1}$");

        var strKey = new KeyConverter().ConvertToString(e.Key);
        if(strKey.Length > 1 )
        {
            strKey = strKey.Replace("NumPad", "").Replace("D", "");
        }
        if (strKey.Length == 1)
        {
            if (!R.IsMatch(strKey))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the case of letters, and it doesn't cover non-numpad numbers (D0-D9).

Comment: Serves me right for skim reading :-) Updated to a slightly better cludge although other answers are probably more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

Can you put some code to show what you intend? Shouldn't this work for you

```
      if(e.key.ToString().Length==1)

    `Char.IsLetter(e.key.ToString()[0])`
    else

//
```

Comment: e.key.tostring()[0] - so when i push LeftCtrl - char is L which is letter, that's why it doesnt work :)