# How to detect if keyboard has numeric block?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm making a little tool that turns on numlock on keyboard with numeric keypad. I know how to turn on/off numlock with C#, but I do not know how to determine, if the keyboard has a numeric keypad.

Comment: If you find Numlock that itself means numeric keypad exists. Doesn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Key is digit or number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834260/wpf-key-is-digit-or-number)

Comment: @Gul Md Ershad - Please read problem statement carefully. Thanks

Comment: Yes, but laptop without numeric keypad may have numlock accessible through the Fn key. On such a keyboard I do not want to turn on numlock automatically.

Comment: You are enhancing your requirements :-). Please put complete problem statement in your post and your efforts to resolve same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549614/detecting-the-presence-absence-of-a-numeric-keypad

Comment: @Amit I'm not sure what else to say. I have a C # function that turns on and off numlock. I want to use this function to automatically turn on NumLock. But only on keyboards, which have their own physical numeric keypad (not through the function as the MacBook, which have no physical numeric keypad). Unfortunately I have no idea how to determine whether the keyboard has a numeric pad. So I can not provide any code.

Comment: Numlock is numlock. Once turned on, some set of keys will act as numbers on keyboard whether Desktop, laptop or touchpad. So, consider all scenarios and suggest you not to stick with your version of physical and logical numeric keys. iman mir has already provided some insights but i think you are already doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import this API in project:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
```

And use this command to get Numlock status:

```
bool CapsLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
bool NumLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x90)) & 0xffff) != 0;
bool ScrollLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x91)) & 0xffff) != 0;
```

None NumLock Return 0