# SuppressKeyPress Property of KeyEventArgs not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, errorprovider

After spending 90 minutes searching for a solution to this simple problem I have to post a question in shame.

I'm working on a WPF project where the user inputs text. I want to check the inputs while the user is typing, display a tool tip and ideally  block characters that are not allowed. Basically it's this thread:

[How do I validate characters a user types into a WinForms textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819532/how-do-i-validate-characters-a-user-types-into-a-winforms-textbox/5819681#5819681) or this

[Is there a best practice way to validate user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430488/is-there-a-best-practice-way-to-validate-user-input/15430582#15430582)

```
private void NameTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.???
    }
```

I created this code behind by double clicking in the KeyDown-Property Field in the designer (just mentioning this if I messed up there).

[Screenshot of the Property Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60mfA.png)

I can not access the e.SupressKeyPress Property. Why?
As of the Properties offered by VS I think that *e* is of the wrong Type or in the wrong context here.

[Intellisense Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0DHY.png)

### Edit1

```
private void NameTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var strKey = new KeyConverter().ConvertToString(e.Key);
        if (!strKey.All(Char.IsLetter))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks to @rokkerboci I was able to build something that kind of works.
Yet I think it is overly complex. So improvements are still welcome :)

**New Error** When Creating a Message Box the application hangs without an exception thrown.

Comment: And Merry Christmas to everybody hanging out on SO on Christmas Eve :)

Comment: Ask a new question about your new problem.  Be sure to document it well with repro code and the stack trace of the hung main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **WPF**, which **does not** include the **WindowsForms** specific SupressKeyPress property.

You can do this in WPF by using the KeyDown event, and setting the `KeyEventArgs.Handled` property to true (it tells the handler, that it doesn't have to do anything with this event.)

```
private void NameTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("delete pressed");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have found a perfect answer to your question:

C#:

```
char[] invalid = new char[] { 'a', 'b' };

private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in invalid)
    {
        if (e.Text.Contains(item))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

private void TextBox_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    var text = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)).ToString();

    foreach (var item in invalid)
    {
        if (text.Contains(item))
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput" DataObject.Pasting="TextBox_Pasting" />
```

Comment: So does that mean that tool tips are not supported by WPF?
Would I need to handle each invalid character individually or is something like if(!e.Key is in Char.IsLetter) possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The handled property is basicly the same as the SupressKeyPress property. If you don't want a key to do anything, than just set e.Handled to true if you detect it

Comment: In your answer you handled the the "Delete" key. How could I achieve a statement that only allows Letters?

Comment: I figure that basically this is the only solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834260/wpf-key-is-digit-or-number
that sucks :(

Comment: I have updated the answer, in my testing this worked wonderfully with typing, as well as pasting!